# SELECT from several tables with the same input (SQL SERVER 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

How do I combine a couple of resultsets into one. Say I have these five sql selects, which all take the same 'simple' input (10):

```
SELECT agentid, latitude, longitude, availability, updated
FROM table1
WHERE agentid=10

SELECT email, name, phone, company
FROM table2
WHERE userid=10

SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt1num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype<6

SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt2num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>6 AND propertytype<9

SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt3num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>8
```

How do I UNION or JOIN or sub-query, so that I get a row with all the columns; agentid, latitude, longitude, availability, updated, email, name, phone, company, pt1num, pt2num, pt3num?

Comment: How can U join A table1 to table2 which have no relation in them.. or u forgot it..? Don't U have a foreign key between tables

Comment: Don't really know why I deserve a minus for asking a very clear and concrete question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use [Common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) and then cross join them

```
    with cte1 as ( 
    SELECT agentid, latitude, longitude, availability, updated
    FROM table1
    WHERE agentid=10)
    , cte2 as (

    SELECT email, name, phone, company
    FROM table2
    WHERE userid=10)

    , cte3 as (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt1num
    FROM table3
    WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype<6)

    , cte4 as (SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt2num
    FROM table3
    WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>6 AND propertytype<9)

    ,  cte5 as (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt3num
    FROM table3
    WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>8)


SELECT [youfieldlist] 
FROM 
  cte1, cte2, cte3, cte4, cte5
```

Another way is to use inline views

```
Select [your field list]
FROM (
SELECT agentid, latitude, longitude, availability, updated
FROM table1
WHERE agentid=10 ) t1,
(
SELECT email, name, phone, company
FROM table2
WHERE userid=10) t2, 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt1num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype<6) t3,
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt2num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>6 AND propertytype<9) t4,
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS pt3num
FROM table3
WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype>8) t5
```

These are only really reasonable if you know each select is only going to return one row

You could also use local variables to do each select

```
DECLARE @agentid int, @latitude int , ... 
SELECT   @agentid = agentid,  @latitude = latitude, ...
        FROM table1
        WHERE agentid=10

DECLARE @pt1num int
 SELECT @pt1num  = COUNT(*)  
    FROM table3
    WHERE agentid=10 AND propertytype<6
```

and then select them out

```
SELECT  @agentid agentid,  @latitude latitude, ... @pt1num...
```